# What does 'Defence' do?

Tags: mario-strikers-charged

I have seen four stats: movement, passing, shooting, and defence. I understand what the first three do, but what does defence help with? Does it give you a performance boost on your side?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this guide](http://strategywiki.org/wiki/Mario_Strikers_Charged/Characters), defense affects **how far your player can slide tackle**.

> - Movement: Determines speed.
> - Shooting: Determines shot power.
> - Passing: Determines passing speed.
> - Defense: Determines how far a character can slide tackle.